# 150cc scooter won't start

Tags: starting, scooter

Scooter will not start,I went riding 1 day,started fine,parked it,went to ride 2 weeks after and it wouldn't start.I was getting a clicking sound from the starter relay,changed it,changed the starter , still won't start.now when I turn the switch on the gauges move,when I bypass the starter with the plies the gauges drop down before I even press the switch to see if it would start.I don't even get a spark when I touch the relay with the plies.

Comment: Discharged battery?

Comment: @Markus +1 in my experience battery (or wiring)  issues are **by far** the most common cause for failed start problems.